# Adding conditional Components to template Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of different events such as below which is being imported as `logTypes`

```
export default {
  LOGIN: "login",
  LOGOUT: "logout",
}
```

And I have 2 different components for both of these events.

```
<LogTypeLogin :item="item" />
<LogTypeLogout :item="item" />
```

in my template, I have this

```
<template #item.event="{ item }">
  <div v-else-if="item.action === logTypes.LOGIN">
     <LogTypeLogin :item="item" />
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="item.action === logTypes.LOGOUT">
     <LogTypeLogout :item="item" />
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Nothing
  </div>
</template>
```

Everything is working fine but I want to make it more readable such

in `<template #item.event="{ item }">`

I want to loop through `logTypes` and select Component on the basis of that instead of if and else?

any help will be wonderful. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to name the components with `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT` as in `logTypes` object:

```js
components:{
   LOGIN:LogTypeLogin ,
   LOGOUT:LogTypeLogout
}
```

then use the buitl-in component `component` and bind the `is` prop to `item.action` :

```html
<template #item.event="{ item }">
  <component v-if="item.action" :is="item.action" :item="item" />
  <div v-else>
    Nothing
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and excellent answer. but can you answer one more thing, if I have this `@openCameraDialog="openDialog"` as well such as `<LogTypeLogin :item="item" @openCameraDialog="openCameraDialog" />`  what we will do about `openCameraDialog` ?

Comment: You could just add it next to `is` like `:is="item.action" @openCameraDialog="openCameraDialog"`

Comment: Do you think it will work? the above solution? You didn't use the logTypes anywhere? logTypes are in small cases as well as in `item.action` its small cases but CAPITAL ones are just to make them as constant and for using in other files.

Comment: it should work, did you try that?

Comment: yes it just says `Import LogTypeLogin..The "LOGIN" component has been registered but not used` I think you are missing the main point. item.action doesn't even have the value `LOGIN` but `login`

Comment: I can't guess the details of your code, please share an example in codesanbox

Comment: its very clear here `v-else-if="item.action === logTypes.LOGIN"` item.action is being compared with `logTypes.LOGIN` which has the value `login` a string.

Comment: just change the components option to `components:{
   login:LogTypeLogin ,
   logout:LogTypeLogout
}`